# Passing parameters to the server (oAuth callback in Stripe Connect)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, oauth, stripe-payments

I am setting up Stripe Connect as explained [here](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/standalone-accounts#sample-code) (Standalone Account). I handle the authorization and the retrieval of the `access_token` on my node server.

The user can visit the link `MY_SERVER_URI/authorize` and will be redirected to a pre-defined stripe `AUTHORIZE_URI`:

```
app.get("/authorize", function(req, res) {
  // Redirect to Stripe /oauth/authorize endpoint
  res.redirect(AUTHORIZE_URI + "?" + qs.stringify({
    response_type: "code",
    scope: "read_write",
    client_id: CLIENT_ID
  }));
});
```

After the user authorizes Stripe Connect, he or she will be redirected to a pre-defined REDIRECT_URI, which in this case equals to `MY_SERVER_URI/oauth/callback`, where the following script is executed:

```
app.get("/oauth/callback", function(req, res) {

  var code = req.query.code;

  // Make /oauth/token endpoint POST request
  request.post({
    url: TOKEN_URI,
    form: {
      grant_type: "authorization_code",
      client_id: CLIENT_ID,
      code: code,
      client_secret: API_KEY
    }
  }, function(err, r, body) {

    var accessToken = JSON.parse(body).access_token;

    // Do something with your accessToken

    // For demo"s sake, output in response:
    res.send({ "Your Token": accessToken });

  });
});
```

Now everything here works fine and the application is able to get the `accessToken`. However, this `accessToken` needs to be saved and matched with the user who is granting the access from the client side.

**My question therefore boils down to, how can I either pass a client-side parameter (like the client-side userId) in the `oauth/callback` `GET` request, or process the server handling on the client side (e.g. a `$http` `GET` request instead of visiting the uri)?** I guess that the later is not the recommended option.

I made two attempts:

- I tried to pass a parameter using a dynamic `REDIRECT_URI`, but the
  problem is that Stripe requires that alle urls need to be specified
  first (resulting that  no parameters can be passed in the redirect
  url).
- I tried to access the `MY_STRIPE_URI/authorize` with a `$http` `GET` request, but this gave me the obvious error *No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource*

What can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally your scenario is as follows:

1. Make request to some route on your server and store the user's id there: `req.session.user = {id: '...'}`
2. From that route redirect the user to the third party authorization URL
3. In the route where you receive the access token, store it in the session as well: `req.session.user.access_token = '...'`
4. Use that access token for subsequent requests to the Stripe's API

Note:

1. Don't try to hack the `authorization_code` OAuth flow
2. You may find [Grant](https://github.com/simov/grant) easier to use for that type of OAuth flow, [Stripe](https://grant-oauth.herokuapp.com/#/stripe) is supported
3. Relevant [comment](https://github.com/simov/grant/issues/34#issuecomment-143852669)

Comment: Sounds promising. However, I get the error: TypeError: Cannot set property 'user' of undefined (there is no req.session??)

Comment: Well, you need to mount the default [session middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session) or similar first.

Answer (score 11):

You have to pass your user id as "state" parameter and Stripe will return it on the callback. The only way I found to avoid session

Comment: I wouldn't pass the user id as "state", but some sort of identification token for your user. Otherwise when I get redirected to create my stripe account i can replace the url https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&scope=read_write&client_id=xyz123&state=1 by https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&scope=read_write&client_id=xyz123&state=2 and my token will be registered with user 2 instead of user 1

Comment: You can use something like a JWT https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken to insert a payload (json object of variables in this case) while keeping things secure. This works well if you are using cloud-functions and don't have session state